# Magento2 search result css issue

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.3 CE on ubuntu 18 with SM Moonlight theme, the issue is when I search any product it shows suggested products but without loading CSS and template.
Here is the image for view https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXczs.jpg
It also shows 500 (Internal Server Error)  on the search result page.

Comment: remove var/cache and var/view_preprocessed and run all command and check

Comment: removed these folders and run commands still same issue

Comment: search but click after css or js are load ??? check your console

Comment: If products are found during it shows internal server error 500 in the browser console, and if the product is not found it show no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solved my issue.

`<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

$productData = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
$rfqonlyProduct = $productData['rfq_only'];
?>`

This line of code was throwing error before.

`$product_id = $currentProduct->getId();`

Answer (score 0):

Check if there's a permission issue with var and pub/static folder. Please give full permission to your var and pub/static folder.

Once permission applied to a directory, run below commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

At last, remove your browser cache and check again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Applied all steps, Still same issue search result with no css and js applied

Comment: Enable the error reporting and check if there's any error reported or logged.

Comment: If products are found during it shows internal server error 500 in the browser console, and if the product is not found it show no error

Comment: Getting below error in error.log file, I have noticed not all products search throwing error, some products search are working without any error. `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in /var/www/html/app/design/fronend/Eotrace/base/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml:11\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include()\n#1 /var//www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271): `

Comment: Try `if (!$product->getId()) to if (!$product)` in code if if helps!

Comment: In which file to put this code. Can you describe more specifically?

Comment: Check /var/www/html/app/design/fronend/Eotrace/base/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml:11

Comment: Here is the code @ Bhaumik 1987  `<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$currentProduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product information
$product_id = $currentProduct->getId();
$productData = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
$rfqonlyProduct = $productData['rfq_only'];
?>`

Comment: Try this //get current product information 
  if (!$product) {
   
   $product_id = $currentProduct->getId(); 
   $productData = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id); 
   $rfqonlyProduct = $productData['rfq_only']; 
  }

Comment: after using your code now appearing below error `Notice: Undefined variable: product in /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/Eotrace/base/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`

Comment: `if (!$product) { ` this code showing error variable $product is not defined.